# Make Akka messages unique/versioned by some attribute

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I have the following use case:

An actor consumes data from some external source, which consists of `key:value` pairs. Then they're passed to an actor that must perform some actions on `key` and the latest `value`, skipping the older ones. Basically I'm seeking to split the mailbox into "subtopics" with capacity of 1.
Is such thing possible with Akka at all? If not, what alternatives to it should I consider?

Comment: Why aren't you prefiltering and only passing the latest values instead? Maybe an example would help to understand your use-case. I don't see the reason for the subtopics?

Comment: The application is in HFT domain and the input is a stream of market tickers, The idea is that, after you've processed the freshest ticker, there's no point in processing outdated market data. So the "topics" or "keys" would be ticker symbols and the values would be their prices.

Comment: Okay therefore, I would preprocess the stream maybe via akka-streams and then only send the "actual" tickinfos to a BalancingPool if the handling for the key:value pairs are equal. Otherwise if you have more than 1 Actor implemented you can first filter the stream and then decide which Actor it should handle. Basically I would even build an Actor system the RootActor/s handle the filtering and then will send it to the according  child for furhter operations. The should do "one" thing and that very good.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a priority mailbox, where the newer messages have higher priority. Take a look at default implementation of [PriorityMailbox](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/mailboxes.html#PriorityMailbox).

It might look something like this (based on the example from the docs):

```
import akka.dispatch.PriorityGenerator
import akka.dispatch.UnboundedStablePriorityMailbox
import com.typesafe.config.Config

type Version = // Long, Date, Timestamp, smth else - must be ordered
case class MyMessage(key: String, value: String, version: Version)

class MyPrioMailbox(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config)
  extends UnboundedStablePriorityMailbox(
    // Create a new PriorityGenerator, lower prio means more important
    PriorityGenerator {
      case MyMessage(_, _, version) => versionToInt(version)

      // PoisonPill when no other left
      case PoisonPill    => 1 // or  Int.MaxValue - 2

      // We default to 1, which is in between high and low
      case otherwise     => 0 // or Int.MaxValue - 1
    })
```

Here `versionToInt` should return some `Int` value that is lower for newer versions of messages (higher priority), say in `2 - Inf` range.

Afterwards you can keep track of highest version processed in your actor and drop all other messages that are older than that version. Either use `become` or just a `var` in your actor for that.

It's worth mentioning that the order of sent messages will be guaranteed by Akka, but eventually it will depend on the sender in which order it emits them and the delays in between, which would affect which messages will get processed.

Comment: I thought of this approach, but wouldn't it be slow? I would need a shared variable across all actor instances, which would force me to use synchronization/atomic values. I'm pretty new to Akka and don't understand everything perfectly. Also I need the messages to be "unique" only between some set (more explanations in a comment to the question), not across the whole stream. I could try modifying this approach by having a shared Map of versions, but it would a) slow everything down b) require some mechanism to evict old keys.

Comment: There should be no shared variables. You need to create an actor per key. Ignoring messages will be cheap. Mutable state that represents latest seen version of a message is safely encapsulated within an actor. Should work very well for millions of actors per JVM

Comment: But how do I ensure that future messages will get routed to the same destination actor? By writing a custom router?

Comment: You can either maintain a map from key to an actor or create actor with key name and get actor by name